How do I compare multiple groups of count data (that are either millions or zeros, with big variances)?
I have three independent groups: treatment, drug 1, and drug 2. For each group, I have bacterial counts in CFU. I'm not very good at statistics, so please bear with me. I know I can't use ANOVA because the distribution is not normal, with some counts being very far apart and a considerable number of zeros (though not excessive). The variances are also unequal within the groups, and the sample sizes are unequal.
I've seen papers suggesting the use of the negative binomial distribution, the Poisson distribution, or a bunch of others. My questions are: Is there a recommended method for this situation? How can I compare models from different classes to determine which is better? I'm mainly using R. Is there a way to test multiple methods in R and have it suggest the best (or close to the best) model? Is this approach even appropriate for my situation? Or should I just not worry too much and use a non-parametric test?
